# How to add null value from a properties file to Map

Tags: java, dictionary, properties, null

I have a `properties` file, the content of which are as follows

```
test=uri=someURI,uname=username,pwd=
```

The parameters are separated by a comma, and the key and values are separated by `=`
I'm using `ResourceBundle.getBundle("fileName")` to read the file and `getString("test")` method to read the entry for `test`.

What I'm trying to to here is get the strings separated by `=` inside a Map, using the following method.

```
public static Map<String, String> configMap(String entry) {
    return Arrays.stream(rb.getString(entry).split(",")).map(e -> e.split("="))
            .collect(Collectors
                    .toMap(keyValue -> keyValue[0].trim(), keyValue -> keyValue[1].trim(), (a, b) -> b));
}
```

The methods works in a weird manner though. In the properties file, if I assign a space as a value for `pwd`, it works fine, but if I assign nothing to `pwd`, not even a space, it gives me the following error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

The Map needs to accept null values too, how can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can check the length of the `keyValue` array, and if it doesn't have a second element - put an empty `String` in the `Map`.

Unfortunately you can't put a `null` value in the `Map` when using `Collectors.toMap()`.

```
return Arrays.stream(rb.getString(entry).split(",")).map(e -> e.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors
                .toMap(keyValue -> keyValue[0].trim(), 
                       keyValue -> keyValue.length > 1 ? keyValue[1].trim() : "", 
                       (a, b) -> b));
```

Comment: This is giving me a NullPointerException.

Comment: @RoshanUpreti Oh, that's right. You can't put a null value in the Map. Please see edit.

Comment: works as expected now. Thanks for the time and effort.